# Can I Use Wireless G and Wireless N At The Same Time?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am looking at a D-LINK DGL-4500 wireless router for my home office.  I dont know much about wireless networking.  I was reading the comments for that device at [this site](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833127243&Tpk=DGL-4500), and saw how someone mentioned it "couldnt run both 2.4 and 5 Ghz at the same time" and was wondering what that means, and will it affect my setup?

My wife has a 2006 HP laptop with Intel®PRO/Wireless 3945ABG (integrated) and we also have an iMac (2009) with AirPort Extreme Wi-Fi wireless networking (based on IEEE 802.11n draft specification); IEEE 802.11a/b/g compatible built-in.

Can both of these computers hit that wireless router and be able to run at their optimum speed, respectively?

**UPDATE:**  I decided to go with a D-Link DIR-825.  Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it isn't a dual-radio router, it will only be able to run on a single frequency.

Therefore, you won't be able to connect to it on 5Ghz and 2.4Ghz simultaneously, forcing you to only use 2.4Ghz.

The WiFi G devices won't be negatively affected, but the WiFi N devices won't be able to use the new 5Ghz band, which would have had reduced interference.

Comment: I guess that would be what I see being marketed as "dual band"?  I'll look at those.  Thanks!